# How to fix the deployment error in Glassfish?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, glassfish, glassfish-3, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting the following error when deploying the application in the Glassfish server,

"**Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence. Please see server.log for more details**"

Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in JPA provider in GlassFish is EclipseLink. That's why it is expected that GlassFish does not have class files of Hibernate.

Some effort is needed. What should be done is to deploy hibernate libraries as a part of your application. Detailed instructions can be found from [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Detailed+Logging+Output+with+GlassFish+Server,+Hibernate,+and+Log4j).

Comment: Mikko, Thanks for your reply. This is resolved. I got this exception because I failed to add hibernate3.jar in the glassfish\lib folder. Now it works. Regards,
Gnik.